# Am I being run backwards?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, self-referential

Your task is to write a program, function, or snippet that will output one value if run forward, and another if run backward. The program must run without errors.

The output can be any two distinct values, of the same data type. For example, `1` and `3`, `true` and `false`, or `'t'` and `'f'`. In languages without a concept of data types, such as brainf*** or text, any distinct values are allowed.

This is a code golf challenge, shortest answer per language wins. Note that snippets *are* allowed (so something like `1-2` is valid, but don't expect any upvotes).

Comment: Related but IMO not a duplicate: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16043/mirror-quine-or-my-head-hurts

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-output

Comment: Is it just me, or does this seem like it would be an interesting candidate for [tag:code-bowling]?

Comment: @Xcali There'd have to be something a like a [pristine program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/programming-a-pristine-world) rule

Comment: Does backwards mean character by character or line by line?

Comment: @CaptainMan Character by character

Comment: Using a Bytecode, would your reverse the order of Bytes (i.e. the 2 Bytes `AB CD` become `CD AB`), or of the Nibbles (i.e. the 2 Bytes `AB CD` become `DC BA`)?

Comment: @Chronocidal The bytes

Comment: As much rep as someone wants if said person can think of a 1 byte answer.

Comment: Can the output be nondeterministic? (But they will always still be different)

Comment: @pxeger No, sorry

Answer (score 73):

## Python 3, no comments or string literals, 106 bytes

```
x=quit
y=x.__class__
y.__add__=print
y.__pos__=x
x+x++x+x
x=__sop__.y
tnirp=__dda__.y
__ssalc__.x=y
tixe=x
```

I've never liked how comments and string literals let you "turn off" most of your language's syntax in challenges like this, so I wanted to see how far I could golf things without using either comments or string literals. This is what I came up with.

Since I don't have any way to disable the syntactical significance of parentheses, I cannot use the function call operator. Any attempt to do so would result in the reversed code having a closing parenthesis before the first opening parenthesis, which is invalid outside a comment or string literal. I also can't use `def` or container literals (aside from unparenthesized tuples), and my access to language features is in general extremely restricted.

One thing I *can* do is take advantage of Python's operator overloading to call functions implicitly. My ability to define any classes or functions is extremely limited, but fortunately, there are enough tools lying around in the built-in namespace for me to use. Most built-ins don't let me perform the attribute assignment I need to redefine their operator overloads, but (unless Python is run with one of the flags that disables `site` importing) the auto-imported `site` module adds `quit` and `exit` objects to the built-ins. These objects are instances of non-C classes, so I can reassign their operator overloads.

Setting `__add__` to `print` lets me use addition to print things, and setting `__pos__` to `quit` or `exit` lets me use the unary `+` operator to abort the program before the rest of the code runs. Without setting `__pos__`, I would need a bunch of additional code to make sure the "backwards" part of the code can find all the variables and attributes it needs to not fail. With `__pos__`, I only need to make sure the "backwards" code is still syntactically valid.

Forward, the code prints

```
Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

Backward, the code prints

```
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

(The messages are slightly different on Windows. For platform-independent output at the expense of 3 extra bytes, you can replace the middle line with `x+1++x++2+x`, printing `1` when run forwards and `2` when run backwards.)

---

I also tried to figure out a way to do this by defining my own class instead of messing with `quit.__class__`. I got as far as the following:

```
if.1j:adbmal=1j
class ton:adbmal
a=lambda:j1.fi
j1=a
a.__dict__=a.__globals__
```

`class ton:adbmal` is one of the very few combinations of class name and class body such that the class statement is syntactically valid backward. `tressa`, `led`, `labolg`, `tropmi`, and `esiar` would also have been valid class names (with a different class body, such as `not fi`), but `ton` is the only one where the reversed name can be part of an expression, giving the most flexibility.

`if.1j:adbmal=1j` assigns a value to `adbmal` to make the class body succeed, while still being syntactically valid backward.

The stuff with `a` and `j1` lets me use `j1.ton` to refer to my `ton` class, which is still a valid expression backward.

At this point, I got stuck. I couldn't figure out how to get my class out of `j1.ton` and into a more useful variable. I can't assign attributes on `j1.ton` and still have valid syntax backward, so I can't set operator overloads. I also wanted to set [`builtins.__build_class__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832997/what-does-pythons-builtin-build-class-do) to my class so I could abuse the `class` statement to construct instances without the function call operator, but trying to put `j1.ton` on the right side of an assignment produces invalid syntax backward.

If I had been able to name my class something like `fi` or `tpecxe`, I could have used tricks like `b:j1.fi` to get the class into an annotation and then `a.__dict__=__annotations__` to get it into `a.b`, but I couldn't find any way to get the class statement and the annotation tricks to hook up. Anything that was compatible with the class statement was incompatible with the annotation tricks.

(You might wonder why I didn't abuse `builtins.__build_class__` to call an existing function directly, like `print`. I couldn't figure out a way to do that and have the output be deterministic, and I wanted deterministic output.)

Comment: +1, this is awesome.

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript, 19 bytes

Returns `true` because of the assignment at the end, since JS treats that as defining a global variable. The first part is an arrow function, which is ignored. When run backwards, `eurt` is set to `NaN` (not a number), and since `NaN` is not greater than `true` (or equal), it returns `false`.

```
eurt=>true;NaN=true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P7W0qMS2pKg01ZqroCgzr0TDL9EPzNf8/x8A)

```
eurt=NaN;eurt>=true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P7W0qMTWL9HPmqugKDOvRAPEt7MtKSpN1fz/HwA)

## JavaScript, 3 bytes

A snippet which outputs `1`, or `-1` in reverse. Very simple.

```
2-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69Ew0jXUPP/fwA)

```
1-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69Ew1DXSPP/fwA)

## JavaScript, 7 bytes

Abuses the not equal to operator and the not operator, will output `false`, or `true` in reverse. JavaScript uses `NaN` as not-a-number.

```
5==!NaN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69Ew9TWVtEv0U/z/38A)

```
NaN!==5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69Ewy/RT9HW1lTz/38A)

## JavaScript, 18 bytes

Another boring solution, with comments instead of subtraction. Returns `1`, or `2` in reverse. I included the `print` statements in these.

```
print(1)//)2(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69Ew1BTX1/TSKMkL7Oo4P9/AA)

```
print(2)//)1(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69Ew0hTX1/TUKMkL7Oo4P9/AA)

## JavaScript, 7 bytes

Similar to the previous answer, but with assignment instead of equal-to. Uses the `atob` variable, which is a builtin in browser Javascript (decodes base64). Since TIO doesn't include browser builtins, I defined it just to keep it from erroring. Works as expected in console. Return `true`, or `false` in reverse.

```
2!=atob
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P7EkP8k2rTQvuSQzP09Ds7rWmqugKDOvRMNI0RYkp/n/PwA)

```
bota=!2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P7EkP8k2rTQvuSQzP09Ds7rWmqugKDOvRCMpvyTRVtFI8/9/AA)

Comment: Why do you have to use NaN in the second snippet? That can be absolutely anything but 5, as far as I see.

Comment: @someone IDK, didn't think about it I guess. I kinda like the `NaN` being symmetrical trick, so I'll keep it

Comment: I was thinking of `0||1`

Comment: @Bergi That would work too, there're a huge number of 3-5 character solutions possible

Comment: @Bergi I just realized, that would be 1 every time...

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Ouch. Looks like I was *not* thinking. `||` can still be used, but as you say there's a lot of boring 3-5 character solutions.

Comment: Here's a function answer: `_=>1|0<=_` and `_=>0|1<=_`

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
1"_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZXi/2tyFaWWpRYVp9rqKcQrGXJxpSZn5CukKRjCGJaWEJa6OoSGKocpgHEtLf8DAA)

#### one or infinity...

- `1"_` is the constant 1, turned into a verb of rank `"` infinity `_`.  Hence always returns 1.
- `_"1` is the constant infinity `_`, turned into a verb of rank `1`.  Hence always returns infinity.

Comment: How does the ranking work? I've never seen anything like that in a programming language.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms It's rank in the dimensional sense of linear algebra, rather than the colloquial sense of "a ranking."  The basic idea is simple enough, but [understanding it thoroughly is a serious undertaking](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_i_verbs_have_r.htm#_Toc191734333).

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/b8P9/AA)

Prints 1.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Q@/9/AA)

Prints 2.

The reason for this is that Jelly's dyad-nilad structure chains differently on either side. `+1` becomes a monad meaning "plus one", which is applied to the Left Argument, which defaults to zero. `1+` does not become a monadic chain here (if I remember correctly - correct me if my Jelly theory is off; I'm a bit rusty on the structural component), but rather is seen as `1` set as the Left Argument, and then `+` is applied as a dyad to `(left, left)` in the default case of no Right Argument, giving `1 + 1`.

Great challenge; I almost feel like this is a cheese. I don't know if I should be happy with this solution or feel bad for having such a short and trivial solution >_<.

This uses Jelly's structure to be fancy. A more boring answer would just be `01` (prints 1) and `10` (prints 10), or any other two-digit number and its reverse (that isn't a palindrome).

Comment: Cool solution! The higher level languages might be interesting to see, as well. +1

Answer (score 6):

## **bash, 12 bytes (no comments or string literals)**

```
echo 0$ ohce
```

Prints "0$ ohce"

```
echo $0 ohce
```

Prints "bash ohce"

## **bash, 11 bytes (no comments or string literals)**

```
echo ftnirp
```

Prints "ftnirp"

```
printf ohce
```

Prints "ohce"

Answer (score 4):

## brainf*** 2 bytes

```
+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fW@//fwA)

Outputs 1 forwards, 0 backwards. Really randomdude999's answer

Comment: Doesn't simply `+.` also work? It would output a 1 if run forwards and 0 if run backwards.

Comment: @randomdude999 Whoops, yeah it does. Man I'm bad at this so far

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 10 bytes

```
Print@ohcE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCE/I9n1/38A)

Prints `ohcE`.

```
Echo@tnirP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/981OSPfoSQvsyjg/38A)

Prints `>> tnirP`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 2 bytes

```
.1
```

Prints `0.1`.

```
1.
```

Prints `1`.

Both numeric (double).

[tio](https://tio.run/##K/r/31CPS8/w/38A)

Less trivial? and for an explicit true/false

```
2>1
# TRUE

1>2
# FALSE
```

[tio](https://tio.run/##K/r/38jOkIvL0M6I6/9/AA)

Comment: Shouldn't `1.<1` be `1.>1`?

Comment: @Adám: Yes. Got my eyes crossed.

Comment: @AkselA That seems to happen a lot in this challenge...(-:

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Is that a reversed sad smiley face? ;-)

Comment: @RobinRyder No, just a sideways one. I always forget which side the eyes are supposed to be on (;;;)

Answer (score 4):

## [POSIX sh](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) (Dash, Bash, Zsh, ...), 3 bytes

```sh
: !
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/30pB8T8XkOBKTc7IV1Cx51JUsIKz/wMA)

The builtin `:` discards its arguments and exits `0` (true). Reversed, `!` negates the exit code of `:` and exits `1` (false).

Comment: very cool. i was going to write a cross platform answer `echo sey` <=> `yes ohce` but this is way golfier!

Answer (score 4):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 2 characters, 1 byte in 7's encoding

```
31
```

[Try it online! (forwards)](https://tio.run/##M///39jw/38A)

[Try it online! (reversed)](https://tio.run/##M///39D4/38A)

This should be the first valid 1-byte solution (because the existing 1-byte solution in BCT requires a particular value on its input to work, and isn't counting it in the byte count – that could only be assumed in a full program, and BCT full programs can't do I/O and must wipe all their working memory to be able to halt, thus have no way to halt with a value). 7's encoding packs multiple characters into a single byte: here are `xxd` hexdumps for the forward and reverse programs:

```
00000000: 67                                       g
```

```
00000000: 2f                                       /
```

This conceptually outputs a string: `31` for the forwards program, and an empty string for the backwards program. The output encoding is set to be the same as the input encoding; so if you encode the program in 7's encoding, you'll get a single byte of output which encodes the string `31` (and if you use ASCII instead, you'll get two bytes that encode the string `31` in ASCII).

### Explanation

On the first pass through the program, the `3` appends a "print and pop" command to the stack, and the `1` appends a "push empty stack element" command to the stack. So, we end up forming a program on top of the stack. At the end of the first pass through the program, 7 will run the resulting program, but without popping it from the stack.

With the forward version of the program, the "print and pop" command will attempt to print the program consisting of a "print" command and a "pop" command. That isn't a valid literal, so the 7 interpreter will construct code that's capable of constructing that stack element and print that instead; in this case, the code it finds for for "push a stack element that generates a 'print and pop' command then a 'push empty stack element command'" is `731` (i.e. basically the program we wrote, although our program appends to an implicit empty stack element, whereas the reconstructed program makes a new one). The print routine interprets the `7` as a command to set the output encoding to the same encoding that was used for the source code, and then the `31` is interpreted as a literal and gets printed. The command in question pops two things in total (the thing it's printing and the element below), so the stack now contains no data and thus there are no more passes through the program; it just exits (even though we push an empty stack element after this point, those don't affect the end-of-program behaviour).

With the reverse program, we're pushing the empty stack element before the print attempt, rather than the other way round, so it's now an empty string that gets printed, and the remnants of the program (which are below it) get popped without printing them. Everything is now the same as in the forward program, so the reverse program also exits naturally and without error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 bytes

```
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f0OD/fwA)

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 bytes

```
01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fwPD/fwA)

When run forwards, it prints `10`. When run backwards, it prints `01`.

I might try to create a non-trivial answer soon, as this seems like a really great challenge!

Comment: Also works in pretty much every language REPL.

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

Decrement empty value & push 1.

```
D1
```

Reversed program decrements 1, outputting 0.

```
1D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/F8P9/AA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

The exact same answer ported to a different language.

```
<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxvD/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 11 bytes

```perl
say$-,$$yas
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFV0dFpTKx@P//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Outputs `0` when run forward.  Outputs the current process number followed by 0 when run backwards.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

This one does not have any nilads or dyads inside the program. Just monads.

```
±(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///QRo3//wE)

### Explanation

```
±  Find absolute value of the implicit 0
 ( Decrement 0, resulting -1.
```

Reversed:

```
(  Decrement 0, resulting -1.
 ± Find absolute value of -1, which results in 1.
```

Comment: Interesting, using absolute value. +1

Answer (score 3):

## [HolyC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TempleOS), 12 bytes

Like the C version, except using the implicit print in HolyC

```
"0"; // ;"1"
```

Prints 0

```
"1"; // ;"0"
```

Prints 1

Spaces required by the compiler :)

Answer (score 3):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 3 bytes

```
:
+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL///fikv7/38A)

Prints 0

```
+
:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fm8vq/38A)

Prints 1

---

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 10 bytes

```
 ==
:+
==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fwdaWy0qby9ZW4f9/AA)

Prints 0

```
 ==
+:
==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fwdaWS9uKy9ZW4f9/AA)

Prints 1

Answer (score 3):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
tis,A NAMETAG
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?K8ks1nFU8HP0dQ1xdP//PykxBQA)

Prints ASCII character 1 (SOH).

```
GATEMAN A,sit
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?c3cMcfV19FNw1CnOLPn/PykxBQA)

Prints ASCII character 0 (NUL).

*The previous answer ends with an "Unexpected EOF" error forwards because the END command (any ten-letter word) is omitted, and a "Mismatched IF/EIF" error backwards because EOF is encountered before an IF/EIF loop can end. The following answer terminates properly.*

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 51 bytes

```
the difference between I and certain ridiculous men
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?BcGBDYAwCATAVX4dx6DwjST6Jkjj@PWuTyJyThblxGB/pHDAFHBWWwqVkb6uZ724qb2HxQ8)

Prints a newline.

```
nem suolucidir niatrec dna I neewteb ecnereffid eht
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?BcGBDYAwCATAVX4dx6DwjST6Jkjj@PVOvPGu51qekQWlddERMhwQ@TUH6GJxzgzw7L2HxQ8)

Prints a newline and a "vertical tab" character.

(I really wanted to be able to make the programs make sense both backwards and forwards, but I'm not sure that's possible in English, and I don't know any other languages to try that out with.)

Comment: The only thing I can think of that makes sense forward and backward (actually, neither) is `tacocat racecar wow`.

Comment: `TIS A NAMETAG` -> a person getting excited about a nametag. `GATEMAN A SIT` A command unto Gateman A; he must sit.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Good one!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 52 bytes

```
a=0--
--b tnirp=b#a
niam=main
1#a=niam
main=print a
```

==> prints "1"

```
a tnirp=niam
main=a#1
niam=main
a#b=print b--
--0=a
```

==> prints "0"

Explanation:

```
a=0--
-- FWD: define constant "a" to be 0 / BWD: No-op                                 --

--b tnirp=b#a
-- FWD: No-op / BWD: define a function "#" in two arguments and prints the       --
-- second                                                                        --

niam=main
-- FWD & BWD: define constant "niam" to be the same as "main"                    --

1#a=niam
-- FWD: define a function "#" in two arguments that produces "main" if the first --
-- argument is 1 / BWD: define constant "main" to be the result of the function  --
-- "#" applied to the arguments "a" and 1                                        --

main=print a
-- FWD: define constant "main" to be an IO action that prints the value of "a" / --
-- BWD: define a function "a" in one argument that always produces the value     --
-- of "niam"                                                                     --
```

Of course, there is also the shorter item:

## Haskell, 29 bytes

```
main=print 1--
--0 tnirp=niam
```

which is much less interesting.

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL

Boring solution using comments

```
0⍝1   => 0
1⍝0   => 1
```

Even more boring numeric solution:

```
10    => 10
01    => 1
```

Basic arithmetics:

```
2-1    => 1
1-2    => ¯1
```

Comment: another: `0⊢1` and `1⊢0`

Comment: @Razetime yeah, it can be done using various operators - power, division, etc... but i found it pointless to include it here

Comment: embrace the boring

Answer (score 3):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 31 bytes

```
1 tuptuO >>
> 1
>> Output 1
0 >
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fUKGktKCk1F/Bzo7LTsGQy85Owb@0pKC0BMg2ULD7/x8A), [!enilnO tI yrT](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsGAy1ChpLSgpNRfwc4OyLbjsrNT8C8tKSgtUTD8/x8A)

Hooray for strict parsing rules!

The first and last lines are ignored, because they don't fit the right syntax. They come into action when reversed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig) 0.1.0, \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
,"
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

Argh. Beaten by Halfwit by more than half a byte. In the forward position, it prints a single newline. Backwards, `",`, it prints a comma followed by a newline.

Answer (score 3):

## [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), <s>14</s> 15 bytes

```
x:#
	#$@$#	
#:y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MTv3/v8JKmYtTWcVBRZmTS9mq8v9/AA)

*Updated to add a trailing tab on the second line...*

Here's another one that's not as short, but seems interesting enough to post...

Forwards it prints `x` and backwards it prints `y`.  It works by referencing the `$@` symbol, which is defined as the target being made.  The "command" run is just a comment to the shell, so it's a no-op.  But by default Make echos the commands it runs.

Also, the `$#` reference doesn't cause an error, and evaluates to an empty string, which allows `#$@$#` to work both directions without having to add more characters.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think it should be 15 bytes, because the second line should end with tab. Also I think it would be nice to tell that `$#` is variable with empty value as it confused me a bit at first, because I am not that much familiar with Make.

Comment: Good point...  there is missing trailing tab on the second line.  I'll update the answer.  And I'll add a note about "$#" evaluating to an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bits<sup>1</sup>, 0.5 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
2
```

[Try it Online! (link is to bitstring)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIhIiwiIiwiMDEwMSIsIiIsIiJd) The bitstring form of this is `0101`, which translates to 2.

Reversed - [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIhIiwiIiwiMTAxMCIsIiIsIiJd) (outputs 0)

If we stretch the rules a bit, we can get two bits: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIhIiwiIiwiMTAiLCIiLCIiXQ==) [!enilnO ti yrT](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIhIiwiIiwiMDEiLCIiLCIiXQ==), which respectively output an empty string and 0 - 0 and 1 in unary.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0bp/38A)

Returns the string ' " ' (one set of double quotes)

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
"\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xynm/38A)

Returns "\"

Oops, my earlier answer missed that they had to be the same data type. This answer returns two different strings, and relies on the fact that '\' makes a one character string of the input and that Pyth closes strings implicitly

Comment: Oh, smart, using `\"` to escape a quote

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 17 bytes

```python
print(1)#)2(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1BTWdNIoyQvs6jg/38A)

I promise this is the last trivial/cheese one I post; I'm trying to think of a more interesting solution. If I remember I'll see where I can get with this.

Comment: At this point, Python devs should add tnirp as a function just to mess with y'all.

Comment: @DonThousand haha that would be funny :P

Comment: I keep reading tnirp as turnip

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
1g
```

Returns `1`. Reverse returns `-1`.

`g` is the sign function when it has no arguments, and returns the sign of the argument minus the caller if called with an argument. So `g1` would be the sign of zero minus one because the default input is 0

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MWc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 32 bytes

Basically just a port of the Python answer.

```
System.write(1)//)0(etirw.metsyS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVcNQU19f00AjtSSzqFwvN7WkuDL4/38A)

Comment: I think you mean `System.write(1)//)0(etirw.metsyS`. Remember that orientation of brackets is preserved when the code is reversed

Comment: Thank you for noting that.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Push 1 onto the stack & negates. (This results in -1)

```
1(
```

Negate empty value & push 1. Output 1 implicitly.

```
(1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUOP/fwA)

Comment: `3Í` would also work. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@HDv//8A "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 6 bytes

```
p:stup
```

Output

```
:stup
```

Reversed output

```
p
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ceylon (Snippet), 20

The same trivial thing as in many other languages:

```ceylon
print(1);//;)2(tnirp
```

Outputs 1.

```ceylon
print(2);//;)1(tnirp
```

Outputs 2.

Given that parentheses need to be in the right order and you need `print` for output, I don't think this can be improved.

A full program or function needs even more braces/parentheses mirrored, so no chance of getting it better.

## Ceylon (anonymous function), 17

If we don't need to output anything, but just return it from an anonymous function, then this is enough:

```ceylon
()=>//
1.2
//>=)(
```

A function which returns 1.2 (a floating point value).

```ceylon
()=>//
2.1
//>=)(
```

A function which returns 2.1 (a floating point value).

## Ceylon (expression with return value), 3

If we accept just an expression (which then can be printed), then we don't even need any comments:

```ceylon
2.1
```

Gives 2.1 (a floating point value).

```ceylon
1.2
```

Gives 1.2 (a floating point value).

[Try all of them online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=03f2449ba0a874bd89d095ea1e4aeb94)

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), no comments or string literals, 19 bytes

```
0 * 0 * 0
0 * 1 * 0
```

Reversed:

```
0 * 1 * 0
0 * 0 * 0
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?9847ee2afaec86aacfec82b6ebcb9ca8)

The code runs without errors, but does loop forever. Prints '0' forward, prints '1' reversed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 2 bytes

```
@,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//930Pn/HwA)

Prints nothing by default, prints a null byte if reversed

Answer (score 2):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 2 bytes

```
oi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/P/P/fwA)

Boy, if that fruit hanged any lower, it'd be underground I tell you.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC Non-trivial, 4 <s>5</s> bytes

```
Disp "Disp :
```

This outputs 'Disp :'

Since TI-BASIC is token based, reversing it gives

```
:Disp "Disp
```

which outputs 'Disp'

Let me explain.  'Disp ' is one token which prints the given string to the home screen.  First we are giving it a string of 'Disp :', so simple there.  When reversed, since each 'Disp ' is one byte, we get the reversed code above.  This reversed code starts with a ':', which ends the line, and means nothing here.  The remaining code is 'Disp "Disp ', which runs and outputs 'Disp ' to the home screen.

## TI-BASIC Trivial, 2 bytes

If a program ends with a values, then it outputs it.  This lets us do

```
12
```

which outputs 12, and reversed is

```
21
```

which outputs 21.

Comment: I was waiting for a TI-Basic answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 14 bytes

```
()->1;//;0>-)(
```

Simple function that uses comments to exclude the other part. Outputs 1, and reversed outputs 0.

Answer (score 2):

### [Bitwise Cyclic Tag](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag), 2 bits (0.25 bytes)

With an input of `1` this should either set the data string to a null string or a string of length 2 in its next iteration.

```
01
```

### Explanation:

```
0  Delete the leftmost data bit.
   Halt. No more instructions executed.
 1 Not executed
```

### Reversed:

```
1  If the left-most data-bit is 1,
 0 Append a 0 to the data-string.
```

Answer (score 2):

## AppleSoft Basic, 3 bytes

`0?1` outputs `1` 
`1?0` outputs `0`

<s>`0?"?1` <=> `1?"?0`</s>

[verified here](https://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Halfwit](https://github.com/chunkybanana/halfwit/), 1 byte

```
*k
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoYWxmd2l0IixudWxsLCIqayIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

The *second* valid one-byte solution :P

`*` is multiplication, multiplying two 0s. `k` is a digraph character, and on its own a NOP, but `k*` is exponentiation.

Alternatively, anything that's a single char before `>` works as `>` delimits a compressed integer, so `>x` will push some number, and `x>` will apply `x` then push 0.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 2 bytes

```
-`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/1834f9/AA)

Forwards outputs `1` and backwards shows `-1`.

Why?  Forwards:

```
 -   : subtract top two stack entries, when empty produces "0" 
  `  : increment top of stack, produces "1"
```

Backwards:

```
`   : increment top of stack, when empty produces "0"
 -  : subtract top two stack entries, produces "-1"
```

Comment: ok... will do.  I thought multiple entries from the same person were discouraged.  My bad...

Answer (score 2):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
+2
```

[Run forwards](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=KzI_), outputs `3`:

```
+   Increment
 2  Two
```

[Run backwards](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=Mis_), outputs `8`:

```
2   Double
 +  Four
```

In fact, any program consisting of two characters from the set `2<+-/%` will work. [Here](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=MSgxLiguKT8pKDEoPC4pKCg8LikpPyk/CiooKScoKDI8KSgyKykoMi0pKDIvKSgyJSkoPCspKDwtKSg8LykoPCUpKCstKSgrLykoKyUpKC0vKSgtJSkoLyUpKQ__) are all the possible combinations together with their outputs. We could also add `0` to the set if it weren't for the "same data type" restriction.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
2-1
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIyLTEiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Running it forward gives `1`, running it backwards gives `2`.

This because vyxal's syntax is weird:

```
ab- (vyxal) = a-b (py)
```

Comment: This can be `10` for 2 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X9vw/38A)

There are probably loads of different 2 byte answers.

#### Explanation

`+1` states that `1` is the result of the sum of an unknown list of integers, which is obviously `true.` (there are infinitely such lists).

`1+` states that we can sum the list `1` into some result, which is obviously `false.` since `1` isn’t a list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
c1
```

Return x rounded up to nearest multiple of N => output 0

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YzE)

```
1c
```

x default to 1 => output 1

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MWM)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 2 bytes

```php
12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/f0Oj/fwA)

Prints `12` ...

```php
21
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fyPD/fwA)

Prints `21` ...

---

Looking for non-trivial solution?

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 11 bytes

```php
<?=1;#;2=?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7W0FrZ2sjW3ub/fwA)

Prints `1` ...

```php
<?=2;#;1=?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WyFrZ2tDW3ub/fwA)

Prints `2` ...

---

Don't like comment abuse?

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 13 bytes

```php
;echo+1-ohce;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkrVOTM/K1DXXzM5JTrf//BwA)

Prints `1` ...

```php
;echo-1+ohce;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkrVOTM/J1DbXzM5JTrf//BwA)

Prints `-1` ...

**Note:** this one is an exact copy of my answer here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193169

Comment: The definition of "reversed" is ambiguous in the question, and could be byte-reversed, as you have, line-reversed... or bit-reversed, which means you can get it down to one byte (eg `J` is binary `0100 1010`, which reversed is `01010 0010`, or `R`). I don't think you can get shorter than that, though, as I don't think sub-byte sizes are valid input to the parser.

Comment: @DewiMorgan Reversed in terms of characters

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I get that it's what you meant, but since it was left ambiguous, it makes that aspect of the request fair game for golfing, too. All three could give interesting results, though I think the bitwise reverse would be the most trivial in many languages, and impossible in others, and the winner would likely be any language which allowed sub-byte inputs; while the command-wise reversal would for once give no advantage to golfing languages, if the number of operators is being counted, rather than number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 21 bytes

```c
puts("");//;)"0"(stup
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@n5uYmaehWf2/oLSkWENJSdNaX99aU8lASaO4pLTgf@1/AA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@n5uYmaehWf2/oLSkWEPJQEnTWl/fWlNJSaO4pLTgf@1/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 3 bytes

```
0@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/AwfD/fwA)

Prints `0` forwards and `1` backwards.

If no output is allowed, then `@1` saves a byte.

Comment: Never realized you made this language...seems pretty cool!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yep! Its almost the only language Igolf in because of that.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol, 2 bytes

```
#1
```

Prints #1

```
1#
```

Prints ##

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 20 bytes

```
S S S N
T   N
S T N
N
N
T   S N
T   N
T   T   S S
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.

Outputs `0`/`-1`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYuTS4GTi4uLE8Ti5FRQ@P8fAA) or [try it online reversed](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0GBk5OLk0uBk4uLi1MBxFJQ@P8fAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation:**

Very minor modification of [my answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192993/52210) (outputting `0` is 1 byte shorter than `1`), so I'm just gonna copy-paste the explanation:

Utilizing the *Exit Program* builtin being a short palindrome `NNN` (also note that without an exit, every Whitespace program would result in an error, making it invalid for this challenge).
The regular program will:

```python
SSSN   # Push 0 to the stack
TNST   # Pop and print the top of the stack as number
NNN    # Exit the program, making everything after it no-ops
```

The reverse program will:

```python
SSTTN  # Push -1 to the stack
TNST   # Pop and print the top of the stack as number
NNN    # Exit the program, making everything after it no-ops
```

Small additional explanation of pushing a number:

- First `S`: Enable Stack Manipulation
- Second `S`: Push a number to the stack
- `S` or `T`: Positive/negative respectively
- Some `S`/`T` followed by a trailing `N`: number in binary, where `S=0` and `T=1`

I.e. `SSTTSTSN` pushes `-10`. Only the first three and trailing `N` are mandatory, so `SSSN`/`SSTN` will both push `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 10 bytes

This was actually hard to optimize, without going into the trivial answer.

```
{@echo"1"}
```

Outputs the **string** `"1"`.

When reversing, you get the following:

```
}"1"ohce@{
```

Outputs the string `}"1"ohce@{`.

As stated in the question: "The output can be **any two distinct values**, of the same **data type**.", and both solutions output a distinct string.

You can test this on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec4bf4b3efa93c63c6c5c9f1458330da0178b6cd
(On line 960, change between the `$code` and `$reversed` variables)

---

---

**SimpleTemplate, 2 bytes**

This one is extremelly trivial:

```
<any 2 different bytes>
```

Reversing them will output whatever is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 4 bytes

```
O@j1
```

Prints `0` forward and `1` backward.

### Forward

```
O     pop stack and print number
 @    end
  j1  not reached
```

### Backward

```
1     push 1
 j    jump next cell
   O  pop stack and print number
  @   end
```

Control flow is more interesting backward because I tried to reduce the amount of redundant characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/9/fIcvw/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 2 bytes

Simply prints 1 because the duplicate instruction duplicates the null string.

```
.1
```

### Reversed

Outputs `11` because that is the value `1` duplicated.

```
1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8/w/38A)

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 4 bytes

Outputs 0 because 1 - 1 is 0.

```
1 1-
```

## Reversed

Outputs `-11` due to concatenation.

```
-1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31DBUPf/fwA)

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 2 bytes (Am I allowed to use the null string?)

Outputs the null string, because the null string from the input minus 1 is still the null string.

```
1-
```

## Reversed:

Pushes -1 onto the stack.

```
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31D3/38A)

Comment: Null string and -1 are same data type in GolfScript?

Answer (score 1):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 2 bytes

Outputs `\n1`, where `\n` represents a literal newline.

```
\1
```

### Reversed

Returns 1, the expression after 1 is ignored.

```
1\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vRrbbts49jn5Cg46C0mJ7Vi5NS3WmHoy6bbYNMnmsouB6zEUm044kSlDkjP2dPo@Dw3QT5hBF@h@wb4tFhi0r/2V/YTuOSQlkTIdp03QIIikw3M/PIeHZIaT9Dziax8/3vtqZZTEK6eMr1B@SYYSvgg/bDCM4pQkk6RCkjRm/KxComRxsR9HA9KPg27KIp4QhfZYAZBye3/v6Jg0iCNeHAT1aJ9su2Pv4eLiQkzTUczJXtSjrsCokHGFuJ6XIaYRyFPI8Mv6hCWMJ2nAu9QF1HQ0DKlHAt4jPAINRwO3BS@uhsUquUYSkdV6lEcDxoM0ihsN3yP9KCaMME7GbSEp08txaj9GjLut7nnsMg5sPRMZ1cyQpaK54pMhjfqmmYiBcIAKPFQxHinnNciLlwjshkGSkKfFkBud/ki7aeYCZN7pMM7STsdNaNivEB4MaIUE8Vm3Qvr4aNSlGThcw1Hgjo8chkgAw0cO6ytgP4Pq6rWQvA2jiKor0g3CMFekP@JdTTJ@IkN4aE6Vn/jzSLfSuedUiA@/nnQgSH/SPHqCQe4LnmNgNa7RyyB0pd9nTAYhH8YyKxvEF6BMvsByW1I9d9sS04UFGhoMViUDgI3l2wLaNW7V2/IrJ48DfkZdsCKkHKOssAV6LrDrVTABWqzteXJcaSa8BLIT@tCA70WcSq2ykThgCSXHMJd24jiKXed///0PifrkHhmMkpSkwQUllKXnNCY@AeVWMdSjAeUpZDAmyouXTg20HgSpK8301FwuM9ZCBNx7EU1Uog1FruN0BmbCgZkI4ue88yyQ7Msh/9ox4v3d/u5u81DlzCeFuzvoAXpWLLTJlmW@GyU1KF8pHbiAexNjv75rY5fA2NXC2ObRMRoxsRi7MIHPybW2lypaMTbRxvRSNiZLZDKjiF7HTHOymT/KBKzkOJ2NLJqILJpTr2@oNJbdiWI3FbAlx@rqZdPVB7snR1/W18szfT3TAZqjeQg6DYKxK6uIrCYTWSxCXClaou6Uqg4PVbkJk1owHFLeczPbRbX5k@TWFuGaqO8JfHveVHTDZEaGLNsdXjEdvr3/7FlT83jhbSVFd3iZV9Xk9eT7gyc7e182fNUsfFP2V@32r5g6Pz7aVUvXl9N5JddZQjSlV@xK10HpeqF03dV7lbxw1q20vknr22l9K@2qSbtqp1210q6ZtGt22jUr7bpJu26nXbfSbpi0G3baDSvtpkm7aafdtNLeN2nv22nvW2m3TNotO@2WlfaBSfvATvvASvsN0K4VtH971jz8q8iFCvlZZ5OlAMG@KnvHHof8fE15eGT2DM3jz@oXYMNRahi60WAIoG14sJDGLqLIwhhBC9AgOF7Dd5l1CQEYfhZpndkFg/Pbi0d33V48f2465ltVg4TBwxiXUa0Aj6/x8A8mo@3m4Sc42Vqd/OXxfI/8cNce6Zh2dG5nw7jqz7ehc9c2/GLacPD0YMdqxsKN7QhOEznj56RIOdfF1potMWOvRJaWSL22cYN2@pe79swf/yxN05PDw5297e@Ve346hywmx/FI7pium@9/vDU5He3s7mxnM56Bm9X@S7JEC5jcY5oRUA5jVhH/MhuE7542dw53jp5@0bZUNe55RJnWscsWEosE9puy5/baM@IK1tgd@e/ybN3dPtz/h@ZJjEfuyU/24rtX5qr07pWxLLnFZi/uubDbqyVpj/FaTIMetCKeV7Fq/e6qxPVKcmUc14MpNioUfGjNEpQMY6KlzrfryIOOWTqjl3r3tqTAW9MsZFEs9atexQD4dX8KsjUf4pep1tdLgLWypK37c5n4/voNlKmXJWG3sGD1zftfTd@8/9XNDsJwI@Q4Zoqm8UR4vJT9gLtsD6U41ElaVb@NWSDPNmtAndJkGHSzc5hTILiQ2CCrKIkiyuMuHabk70E4kvkhaIZBkhjtuJrQU/a9MlPm/avPLe9yiQcwbPwajnODCl8UcnW8JcSLrbz4lhwd4mg8tQ7Cas5VyZyrz1x0pezs2BXWgFvadZXbNWXBlA2vSza8vpUN/TAKZFW9lQGvbxmY30p59JtRY8pLgyhj@olOKXfU0jAl5feSlN8/TQpUzlE6i/mHN2ZcPrz5nM6/OMNN9SPceSe4iFycpqTlE9zMwNIprWUrfYNMFtsh7YqCfFUcYYuluKg1rnPCg1ModWkkD3177IylQYgXIXgezCNehblCz2isJomwpG7MMtwDya7Qyzyz3CDyukPSlA1JlSEzer0Pb27f7MlrEHExNPf@A1wprj8uxSu8JNolBBN3K/BXhyCOhOKbfi1yKa9FLgthYmLhcB6dgi/sF/HWygh3zsk6GTJaeRmwlCNXyJKunFf4IN@RzvWD2LIWlqtNLj5ymNrMivdhECc0W12QHafj1GIpMlAT4yKjRViWO7qwYtB/2M7WVySDtfqFky@nFz2KzZUvv4sjzWzlVhjY2JZUkHcpUzrM00Lo0TXVyBVZzjUpsF5OYVUNLAnMcfIjV6O4db3SDY@sgIk3NSOE68VJCDjL1onIg5H0wjqpsLwXYZRxLeJYRE1KUbHVSlB6YdTIjC0UuosMW6qlXwnma5NMpOKqML1oZ0Mqz1rGuKZKe3oHksiLSE/yUBnZslZpRBa4KgyInMVBn@GGu0VJsVSM/Npvvf5gg/yZYPzAfHjb3NhY2yw5xggzolWRbtPzzPgILaiskLI5JCf8gkc/Ga7Ub@OAV0U0rrL0igIk6GWKwzve8UKJbzwOQIzeacgxSJ@GWq0BkIVPkCidst2IvyrPDRkWErzf7XTE1O90BgHjnY7IAHWnDy4SzsSzJHzGskyK91pT1fMDMeL2aNKN2RAtazj7/T7rMliRYtqnMYXZhv8mEFLED4TxsEyl55Q8IiEEdRScQfZPyF/ooDfq0fXNmmiYpMxa0Ot1ssVDbIscNNcRuwlcQRq5So8BjquT68DCJ8bBk8EoTBt5JyOg5zQcNpxjkI@coFaCVlBT@ZnQSZQTWFpPKYlHvEZOIAWrYsrKXkhK5jh/Gs43jtzELKhJr3QWD9Q6EZmnKhR@11Ck6qfEiP0A0nL@aD1@lJNAHmkCgud9/Pjc/z8)

Answer (score 1):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 4 bytes

```
o1ao
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/z/fMDH//38A)

Outputs `01` if run forwards or `00` if run backward

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/Q6P9/AA)

Prints `2\n1\n` forwards, and `1\n2\n` backwards.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), 2 bytes

```
{!
```

[Try on dis.web!](https://tpaefawzen.github.io/dis.web/#source=%7B%21&input_enc=utf-8&input=&output_enc=base64) Outputs one NULL character.

[!bew.sid no yrT](https://tpaefawzen.github.io/dis.web/#source=%21%7B&input_enc=utf-8&input=&output_enc=base64) Outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

```
0n1
```

[Try it forwards](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMG4xIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

[Try it backwards `1n0`](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMW4wIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 4 bytes

```
?12?
```

prints `12\n\n` forwards and `21\n\n` backwards

Answer (score 0):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 3 bytes

```
i.%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/P1NP9f9/AA)

Prints 1.

`%.i` prints 0.

If it weren't invalid to do an integer and a character, `%#` would've been a nice 2-byter.