# Mirror programs

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

Here is your task, should you choose to accept it: Output (through STDOUT, or whatever is most convenient) some `n` by `m` ASCII art that has at least one line of symmetry and is non-empty. Example:

```
HiiH
iooi
iooi
H!!H
```

This is a 4x4 example output.

(Note: I define an ASCII character to be in the ASCII range 32-126 plus newlines and spaces. *No tabulators*.)

Here's the catch: Your program must also reflect across these same axes AND must be a rectangle in shape. (The output and the input are not necessarily the same width/length). Here is an example in JavaScript:

```
console.log("HiH")//("HiH")gol.elosnoc;
console.log("JvJ")//("JvJ")gol.elosnoc;
console.log("...")//("...")gol.elosnoc;
```

The source code has one line of symmetry (vertical) and the output has one line of symmetry: vertical.

```
HiH
JvJ
...
```

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the highest-voted answer on THIS DATE:

```
3:00 PM
Saturday, September 27, 2015
Eastern Time (ET)
```

will be the winner.

## TL;DR

Write a program with the same axes of reflections as the output, of which is at least one. The output must have side lengths greater than one and must have at least one non-whitespace character.

## EDIT

If a character has a mirrored version (e.g. `(` and `)`), then it should be used instead of itself. Example:

```
[>Hello!\} => {/!olleH<]
```

## Why this question is *not* a duplicate

Said question wished to produce a quine which was the same, forth and back; my challenge is different in two ways. One, it does not necessarily have to be forth and back (up and down, right and left, e.g.). Two, I am not asking for a quine.

Comment: A square always has the "same width". You mean rectangle.

Comment: @minxomat Yes, I do. Lemme edit that.

Comment: Is there a minimum value for n and m?

Comment: @Cole It says `greater than one`.

Comment: @minxomat Oh silly me, I read everything but the TL;DR. Thanks.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why he/she downvoted? I'd love to improve.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I didn't downvote but it probably happened because someone thinks the pop-con tag here makes it too subjective.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Most likely because [tag:popularity-contest] is not very ... popular. But it is refreshing to see something else than codegolf.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Oh, I see. _Is_ it too subjective?

Comment: Your Javascript example shows the reflection of `(` as `)`, but the reflection of `c` is still `c`. Is that intended?

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes, let me clarify.

Comment: Can I make the code a one-liner, as long as it is horizontally symmetrical?

Comment: `/pqdb\ ` have mirrored versions. and some would say `'\``

Comment: I think this challenge is too broad to be interesting. What exactly should voters take into account when choosing their favorite answer?

Comment: I don't think this adds much to [Shortest Mirror Quine Challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12876/shortest-mirror-quine-challenge)

Comment: Your first example is wrong, you should use `!` instead of `i`s in two bottom rows, and the second example should be `console.log("HiH")//\\("HiH")gol.elosnoc;` etc.

Comment: @Voitcus Sorry -- my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Brainfuck, 103 bytes

I made you a sandwich.

```
---+++++++++++++---
[>+++>+<<->>+<+++<]
>...>-.<...>.-<...<
[>+++>+<<->>+<+++<]
---+++++++++++++---
```

Output:

```
***
***
***
```

Comment: Doesn't it say in the question: _Write a program with the same axes of reflections as the output, of which is at least one. __The output must have side lengths greater than one__ and must have at least one non-whitespace character._

Comment: Ah, yes, in the TL;DR rather than the main body of the question.  Time to fix this up!

Comment: +1 for the sandwich :D Also, good strategy to modify cells without printing.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, 29 bytes

```
FG[\@\@)pGpG*0"0*GqGq(@/@/]GF
```

[Demo](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FG[%5C%40%5C%40%29pGpG*0%220*GqGq%28%40%2F%40%2F]GF&debug=0)

I'm assuming that one-liners are okay, otherwise there is an easy fix.

Comment: +1, but shouldn't those `p`s be mirrored as `q`s?  :-P

Comment: They could be, not that it changes anything. I'll change it anyway :D